# Can we refer a storage account properties in second bicep file?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-bicep

I have 2 azure bicep files.

1. Storage.bicep
2. cdn.bicep

Now, I successfully created a storage account and BLOB container from storage.bicep. Is it possible to get the value of storage account properties from storage.bicep to use it in cdn.bicep ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can reference Storage Account in `cdn.bicep` as existing resource if you pass Storage Account name in to it.

```
resource stg 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2019-06-01' existing = {
  name: 'examplestorage'
}

output blobEndpoint string = stg.properties.primaryEndpoints.blob
```

Just make sure you declare `cdn.bicep` has dependency on `Storage.bicep` and is executed after it.

The example above is taken from [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/resource-declaration?tabs=azure-powershell#reference-existing-resources).